# UITextView Select All

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

I'm using UITextView, How can I show Select All in edit menu? then when user click Select All edit menu will show just copy and define?

This code doesn't work:

```
    - (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if (action == @selector(copy:) || action == @selector(select:) || action == @selector(selectAll:))
    {
        return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
    }

    self.TextArea.selectedTextRange = nil;

    return NO;

}

-(void)select:(id)sender
{

}

-(void)selectAll:(id)sender
{
    [self.TextArea setSelectedTextRange:[self.TextArea textRangeFromPosition:self.TextArea.beginningOfDocument toPosition:self.TextArea.endOfDocument]];

}

-(void)copy:(id)sender
{
    self.TextArea.selectedTextRange = nil;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: That behaviour comes natively with uitextview. There should be no need to create select, copy and selectall methods.

Comment: Select All doesn't come natively. @MySpecialPurpose

Comment: Yes, "Select All" is automatically provided by `UITextView`. But it only appears if there is no other selection.

Comment: AS @rmaddy said, the "Select All" option appear. When `editable` is NO you can't have the cursor with no selection so you never see this option. An ugly solution is set editable to YES and `resignFirstResponder` when `textViewDidBeginEditing` ...